# Hiding $location.path and search key

Tags: javascript, angularjs, routes

Can i hide the $location.path and $location.search key from URL?

Now the URL is: `url.com/page.html?key=value`
I need the URL like: `url.com/value`...

Comment: Why do you want to hide it - to keep URL tidy? You can't use the `?key=value` without displaying it, but you can pass that key value pair using something else like and angular Service and take it out of the URL all together.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't test it yet, but I think this will solve your problem.

```
app.run(['$rootScope', '$location', function ($rootScope, $location) {
    $rootScope.$on("$routeChangeStart", function (event, next, current) {
        if (next && next.$$route) {
            var params = next.params;
            var hasQuery = Object.keys(params).length!==0;

            if (hasQuery) {
                event.preventDefault();
                $rootScope.$evalAsync(function() {
                    $rootScope.routeParams = params;
                    $location.path(next.$$route.originalPath);
                });
            }
        }
    });
}]);
```

You can access to routeParams through `$rootScope.routeParams` in each controller.